# Saving objects in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to include an object of a class created by me in a SQL Server database. I am trying to convert it to `VARBINARY`, but the method `Add` doesn't recognize the `VARBINARY` type. The error I get is:

> VARBINARY : undeclared identifier.

I am using namespaces `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Here is my code:

```
MemoryStream^ memStream = gcnew MemoryStream();
StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(memStream);
sw-> Write (eyemax);

SqlConnection^ myConnection =  gcnew SqlConnection();
myConnection->ConnectionString = "Data Source = (localdb)\\ProjectsV13;AttachDbFilename\=C:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\SSDT\\TUKDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";

myConnection->Open();
SqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Features(Face,Eye) VALUES (@face, @eye)",myConnection);
cmd->Parameters->AddWithValue("@face", face);
cmd->Parameters->Add("@eye",SqlDbType(VarBinary));
cmd->Parameters["@eye"]->Value = memStream->GetBuffer();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SqlDbType.VarBinary` instead of  `SqlDbType(VarBinary)`

Comment: No, I tried with SqlDbType.VarBinary at the very beginning and It fails because "SqlDbType is not a valid identifier".